# How can I pipe a python script to lemonbar?

Tags: python, lemonbar

Hi I am making a lemonbar, and I want to make it in python or go or c or something else than shell script, because I want the program to manage the loop, and the threads going on in there.

I found out that I can make a script where I call eg. a python script in every itteration in the loop, like

`bar.sh`

```bsh
while true
do
    python script.py
    sleep 1
done
```

and then the `script.py`

```py
print('%{c}hello')
```

and then I run it like this

```
sh bar.sh | lemonbar
```

That works and I get a `hello` in the middle of the bar. But I would like to do something like this

`bar.py`

```py
while True:
    print('%{c}hello')
```

and pipe it to lemonbar

```
python bar.py | lemonbar
```

This doesnt work. I get a bar but there is nothing on it.

My guess is that is has something to do with the file descriptors used by pythons print function compared to the ones used by my shell `zsh`

**Edit:** I also tried with

```
import sys, time

fd = sys.stdout

while True:
    fd.write('hej\n')
    time.sleep(1)
```

That didnt change anything.

Thank you for reading my question. I hope you can help :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually I just found out how to do it by reading how someone implemented [a module for lemonbar](https://github.com/vimist/lemonbar-manager/blob/master/lemonbar_manager.py)

```py
import time
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

fd = Popen('lemonbar', stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, encoding='UTF-8')

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    fd.stdin.write('%{c}hello')
    fd.stdin.flush()
    print(fd.stdout.read())
```

The trick was to flush the filedescriptor after writing to it

So I could also do it like this

`bar.py`

```py
import time 
import sys
fd = sys.stdout
while True:
    fd.write("%{c}hello")
    fd.flush()
    time.sleep(1)
```

and then run it like normally

```
python bar.py | lemonbar
```